# Python XLRD Module skipping first few rows and reading columns with error:23

Tags: python, xlrd

I am using the following code to open a spread sheet.

```
in_book = xlrd.open_workbook(TPS_XLS_File)
in_sheet = in_book.sheet_by_index(0)
```

when I  try to access the rows in the sheet, the read starts from the 25 the row skipping first 23 rows from spreadsheet.
The `command in_sheet.row(1)` is actually returning the values in the 25 row.The data read from the 25 column is also incorrect with a error message error:23.

It reads the cell values as follows

```
print(in_sheet.col(2))
[empty:'', empty:'', text:'Table/File', error:23, error:23, error:23, error:23, error:23, error:23, error:23, error:23, error:23, error:23, error:23, error:23, error:23, error:23, error:23, error:23, error:23, error:23, error:23, error:23, error:23, error:23, error:23, error:23
```

Please note: The Value "text:'Table/File'"  represent the cell B27 in the spreadsheet, meaning the read is starting from B25.

I have used the same code to load over 1000 files, which all worked except for a hand full of files which seem to fail with this error.

Any help information or suggestion is greatly appreciated.

Thanks
Anil

Answer (score -1):

To large files to use pandas.
You can use pandas' `ExcelFile` [parse](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.io.parsers.ExcelFile.parse.html) method to read Excel sheets, see io docs:

```
xls = pd.ExcelFile('C:\Users\cb\Machine_Learning\cMap_Joins.xlsm')

df = xls.parse('Sheet1', skiprows=4, index_col=None, na_values=['NA'])
```

skiprows will ignore the first 4 rows (i.e. start at row 5), and several [other options](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.io.parsers.ExcelFile.parse.html).